# Detecting if anonymous pipe is writable - to detect when to end process

Tags: windows, process, pipe

So heres the situation (in windows):

- Theres a child process started by the parent, which only has one pipe open, stdout.
- In order for the parent to end the process, it calls pclose
- We can't call read on the pipe to detect if its broken to end the process (because it's a write only pipe, read will always return immediately with an error)

Is there a way to get an event from the pipe when the read end (on the parent) closes? If not, we have to continuously write garbage to the pipe in order to detect when it closes, which is a sub-optimal and wasteful solution.

Comment: If nobody can give you a way to do this, there are better workarounds than polling by writing garbage.  As a few examples, you could use a bidirectional named pipe (with a randomly chosen unique name), or you could create a separate anonymous pipe and attach it to stdin, or the parent could use PostThreadMessage to tell the child to exit, or you could pass the handle to an event object in the environment block.  There are lots of other possibilities.

Comment: The reason I can't use a bidir pipe is that I'm forced to use an implementation of popen that can only use a one way pipe...and it has to be from child to parent. The other reason I can't use any other mechanism, is that I'm relying on a Lua garbage collector to collect the opened handle, which will call pclose, then wait. We need the process to end if that happens. There is no way to get any other code to be called during the garbage collection.

Comment: Have you tried using a zero-length write?

Comment: Well I could do that, but it doesn't quite solve the issue. I still have to poll for the write. I guess this might have to be done if there is no event to detect if pipe is closed.